# Linked List reverse Function is Not Working in java

Tags: java, recursion

I have written a custom method to print reverse of linked list using recursion but it gives some random result.

public class Node {

```
public int data;
Node next;

public Node(int data) {
    super();
    this.data = data;
}

public class NodeImpl {
       public void reverse() {

    Node n = head;
    rev(n);


}

private void rev(Node n) {
    while(n.next != null) {
        n = n.next;
        rev(n);
        System.out.println(n.data);
    }


}
```

}
}

in main class

```
nodeImpl.insert(3);
nodeImpl.insert(5);
        nodeImpl.insert(7);
        nodeImpl.insert(3);

nodeImpl.reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` statement should be an `if` statement. The recursion will print the reverse of the list, then the reverse minus the last element, then the reverse minus the last two...

Try this instead:

```java
private void rev(Node n) {
    if(n.next != null) {
        rev(n.next);
    }
    System.out.println(n.data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick..it worked..but while statement will go till the end of node..why in minus?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question in your comment. Could you please rephrase it? (Please remember to accept answer if it addresses your original post.)